# new Rmarkdown title says invalid, can't even test other title objects

Tags: r, r-markdown

Have tried to create a new R markdown with header

```
---
title: "Test1"
---
```

Have tried updating and reloading, also ran library(rmarkdown) but every time I get the response.

```
> ---
+ title : "TEST"
Error in -title : invalid argument to unary operator
> ---
```

Other portions work in markdown (graphs/tables show up).

Comment: Your Markdown code is being executed as R code. Are you sure it’s inside an RMarkdown file and not in a plan R file? If so, it’s inside an R chunk, or you’ve accidentally pasted it into the R console.

Comment: you may be mistaking the YAML header for a R code chunk

Answer (score 0):

To get the title to be rendered you either need to knit your file or run it through `rmarkdown::render()`. It is not R code, it is a `yaml` header that specifies things for the output document, such as title, author, etc.